# JSF input file tag + ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, file-upload, jsf-2.2

I lost whole day on this issue and got nothing. I know that the question was asked but it was never answered. BalusC said that this issue is fixed in JSF 2.2.5 but either it is not or i do something wrong.

I use h:inputFile tag with ajax to render choosen image in preview div after chosing one from disk. However it's rendered only once and i have to reload page to see next chosen image. It causes more errors. For example when I use SUBMIT button to send chosen image to DB, ajax from commandLink is not executed (image is saved and rendered after page after refresh).

It looks to me like ajax is broken after chosing an image from disk and followed ajax actions are not executed, even they dont belong to h:inputfile.

This is my JSF form (one of its versions because i tried so many tricks)

```
<h:panelGroup class="photo-update" rendered="#{profileBean.page eq 'photo'}">
  Dodaj lub zmień swoje zdjęcie profilowe[...]
  <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGroup id="form-content">
      <h:panelGroup id="current-image" class="current-image">
        <p:graphicImage value="#{imageBean.getUserImage()}"/>
      </h:panelGroup>
      <h:panelGroup id="accept-container-ajax">
        <h:panelGroup id="accept-container" class="accept-container" 
            rendered="true">
          <div class="arrow">
            <img src="resources/images/arrow.png"/>
            <div class="change-text">Zamień na</div>
          </div>
          <h:panelGroup id="new-image" class="new-image">
            <p:graphicImage value="#{profileBean.getConvertedImage()}"/>
          </h:panelGroup>
          <h:commandLink class="btn btn-default ok-button" value="zatwierdź" 
              action="#{profileBean.uploadPhoto}">
            <f:ajax render="accept-container-ajax current-image" 
              execute="@form"/>
          </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGroup>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <div class="btn btn-default change-image-container">
        <a href="#">Zmień zdjęcie</a>
        <h:inputFile immediate="true" id="change-image" 
            class="change-image" value="#{profileBean.image}">
          <f:ajax render="accept-container-ajax" execute="@form"/>
        </h:inputFile>
      </div>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

This is fragment of the bean:

```
public StreamedContent getConvertedImage() throws IOException {
    return userBo.convertPartToStream(image);
}
public void uploadPhoto() {
    this.renderChangeContainer = false;
    if (userBo.addImage(this)) {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null, new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "...", null));
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
            null, new FacesMessage(
                FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "...", null));
    }
}
```

injected BO methods are OK.

Please give me a clue what is going on.

EDIT:
I also see ugly iframe with some response content i guess.

Comment: Which browser is that? I've tried with latest Chrome and the iframe border is gone. Have you refreshed the styles/cleared the cache?

Comment: It's 32.0.1700.76 m version which I think is the newest. The frame is not the biggest problem here.

Comment: I have implemented upload and preview image in RichFaces. Let me know if it is interesting for you.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm still facing this issue... After uploading a file, it's like my ajax doesn't render anything at all. I'm using Wildfly 10. Thanks

Comment: I don't remember to be honest, it was a long time ago. I think that I did some workaround for it